# Javascript equilent of Java's Locale package, or client side approach to rendering lang/script/country codes

Tags: javascript, locale, client-side

Doing server side rendering of HTML templates I find myself using Java's Locale class (via various helper functions) to render language codes (ISO 639-1), script codes (ISO 15294), and country codes (ISO 3166) as their name (i.e. "en" -> "English") in a manner that respects the current user's selected locale.

Now, moving some stuff to client side rendering (with Angular JS), I'm a bit unsure of how to approach this. Doing the code-to-name conversion on the server side and sending locale-aware JSON is one option, but it would add quite a lot of complexity to how various bits of data get JSONified (by having to pass the locale through lots of layers of functions, mainly.)

On the other hand, I can see how a full-on client side version of the Java Locale class would involve sending lots of data to the client, most of which wouldn't get used most of the time.

Are there any emerging best-practices for doing this kind of stuff with largely single-page apps, or any super libraries that would solve my problem in well fell swoop?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the "best practice", but I have also developed a single-page app where I loaded a JSON array with useful JS data on load with ajax. That seemed like the best solution to me if the data is not used right at the beginning of the page.

Otherwise you could just add this script at the end of every page, if you don't mind embedded javascript:

```
<script>
function get_locale(){
    return JSON.parse(/* render JSON.encoded data from server here */)
</script>
```

Sorry if this not really a definitive answer.